# The best setup local connect to graph api

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a dotnet 7 web API, which has access (with managed identity) to most of my infrasctructure components; storage, mssql, etc etc.
All working perfectly.
I am following this article for using managed identity to connect to microsoft graph api (per API and not on behalf on the user): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/multi-service-web-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-cli%2Cprogramming-language-csharp&tryIt=true#code-try-1

and while I am running it in the app, all working smooth, but locally it doesn't work, and now using client_credential flow with the app (which has the graph api permissions set), it feels wrong. Now I am actually mananing for deployed apps the permissions on the managed identity, and locally I have to add client secret, and on top of it, set the permissions on the same "test" web app to graph api.

everything inside me tells me I am doing it wrong, but no clue how to do it different :(

EDIT:
I am using the EnvironmentCredential setup locally to connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Managed identity can't be used to authenticate locally running
> applications. Your application must be deployed to an Azure service
> that supports Managed Identity.

We have a [tip here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?tabs=core6x&pivots=framework-dotnet) although it is not for graph api. Therefore, we need to use some other options when test locally. As we can see in [the comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/multi-service-web-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-cli%2Cprogramming-language-csharp&tryIt=true#example) from the  article you shared.

```
// Create the Graph service client with a ChainedTokenCredential which gets an access
// token using the available Managed Identity or environment variables if running
// in development.
var credential = new ChainedTokenCredential(
        new ManagedIdentityCredential(),
        new EnvironmentCredential());

string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
```

So we could use [EnvironmentCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet#definition) when test locally. Just adding `AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` environment variable in your local machine, then you don't need to use client credential flow instead.

[image]

Comment: I agree on the client_credential flow, but it still leaves me with 2 permissions "set" that I have to maintain. One on the APP registration on Entra ID, (where I have created a client secret and set the permission for this particular app). And one permission set for the managed identity. Is this the way to move forward?

Comment: BTW: if I use the DefaultAzureCredentials and pass that along the client my performance is good. If I use the ChainedTokenCredential my calls rougly take 90 seconds. With DefaultAzureCredentials less then a second. Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: about the performance issue, hmmm, have you tried to put `EnvironmentCredential` before `ManagedIdentityCredential` instead?